# How do I install updates and software on EOL Ubuntu releases?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I have an unusual situation in which I need to use an old version of Ubuntu, and upgrading to a newer release is not an option. As such, I need to be able to install software on it, and run updates up to the point where it was last supported. However, it looks as if Canonical shuts down the servers once a release goes EOL, as the Release file is missing so `apt` won't let me update. Is there a way to get a mirror of the packages in an old Ubuntu release, so that I can update anyway?

Comment: Questions about EOL versions of Ubuntu are off topic here unless they are about upgrading to a current version.

Comment: @user68186 This question is about old versions in general. I was under the impression that the only off-topic questions are questions about specific EOL versions, like how it mentions in this meta post that 21.10 specifically is off-topic https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20059/

Comment: It seems like it should, but the answers and comments don't work. If I change all the `/etc/apt/sources.list` URLs to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` or `us.archive.ubuntu.com` then `apt` still gets 404s and says that it does not have a Release file and that updates are disabled.

Comment: This is where you update your question and be specific about the version, the edited contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and the exact error messages.

Comment: Did you follow the advice on EOL systems, such as https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades ie. repositories are moved and not deleted. Yes some media can be deleted (esp. *if flaws are discovered in installations that aren't fixed via upgrades*) but that's rare too.

Comment: Mirrors, and PPAs are free to drop releases when they go EOL (*in fact PPAs dropping EOL releases is sort of encouraged as builds can no longer be run on EOL releases so the software just becomes more stale*) but the main archive just moves.

Comment: if your release is not in fact EOL, but rather has reached end of standard support, it will still be located in archive.ubuntu.com, but you may need to be signed up for ESM in order to get updated certificates to access the files